# How to "prefer" data from one table over another in SQL, help reformulating.

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Using Sql management Studio on Sql-Server 2005.

I guess my title is not very clear, so although I'd appreciate a direct answer, even better would be help in reformulating the question that I can search for an answer by myself and learn in the process.

Table A contains yearly total sales for various products. This table is updated once a year in Feb/March.There are two consequences to that:  A product that started being sold in, say, July, will obviously only have a six month sale total for the year. Also, any new product will not appear in it before the following year.

Table B is an exception table that gives an estimate for all products not yet in table A or that have a less than a twelve months sale history.

Table C joins the yearly sales with various info from other tables and also contains calculated columns .

In pseudo code what I need is:

> Use sales of product x from Table A in table C unless sales for this product exist in table B.

Basically, data from table B should take precedence over table A wether the record exists in A or not.

Comment: coalese or case statements.

Comment: You can use a left join with an ISNULL or COALESCE on the fields in B and use the value of A in it's place when there is a null in B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do a `LEFT JOIN` and no records exist in `B`, you will get a `null` for the column values in `B`.  So to "prefer" valued that exist in `B`, use `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(B.Sales, C.Sales) AS Sales
FROM ...
```

Which loosely translates to "If `B` has a `Sales` value, use it, otherwise use the value from `C`."

*Technically* it means "take the first non-null value from `B.Sales` and `C.Sales` (in that order)"

Comment: As C is the end table should not it be " Select Coalesce (b.sales, A.Sales) from... ?

Comment: Well it's not completely clear from your description - feel free to adapt to your needs.